# Angular 2 cannot access classes functions

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the Known class where theres a function called checkRev, but when I try to use it on onNgInit it says "this.known.checkRev is not a function"

My class:

```
export class Known {
   constructor(args...){}
   public checkRev(){
    code...
   }
}
```

My component

```
export class KnownItem implements OnInit {
@Input('userInfo') known: Known;
ngOnInit(){
   this.known.checkRev();
}
```

@edit 
I'm passing the known object by input

```
<sh-known-item *ngFor="let known of knowns" [userInfo]="known"></sh-known-item>
```

array of knowns

```
private knowns: Array<Known> = [];
```

pushing into the array

```
this.knowns.push(new Known(args..));
```

@EDIT 2
I have code inside of checkRev() its just too long to put it here

Comment: `console.log` out `this.known` and see what's actually getting passed in.

Comment: Not sure but have you tried `@Input() known: Known;`, how are you passing the known variable?

Comment: I think that you should use ngOnChange function. You must be sure, that Known object has already been passed when you called method on that.

Comment: but everytime that changes it will run the function again right?

Comment: How does your 'knowns' array looks like?

Comment: edited again please read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some attributes for `Known`, whatever that might be for you, you have to have something to be able to perform functions on that object.

So e.g your class should look like:

```
export class Known {

    name: string

   constructor(name: string){
       this.name = name;
   }
   public checkRev(){
     console.log('fired!')
   }
}
```

Then your code should work as should. Tested it, and it worked fine! Here is a 
working **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CE2bfNZKWfmnecTpswbt?p=preview)**

Comment: It doesnt even matter  if theres code or not, its not recognizing as a function thats the problem

Comment: Updated class a bit, to actually have values in the object. Included, working plunker.

Comment: Lucas, did this answer help you? :)

Comment: I'm updating another things now.. I'll see later.. but you are right this should work and this  is what I'm doing..

Comment: AJT Now its working, not sure why maybe was the Reflective Injector, or ng serve didn't detect the changes, anyways if It happens again I'll edit the   post, for now its answerd.

Comment: Well the most important thing is that it works! Sure come back if something happens, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to pass it as an input, you can just implement it in constructor method like

```
export class KnownItem implements OnInit {
  constructor (private known: Known){}
  ngOnInit (){
    this.known.checkRev()
  }
}
```

Comment: @LucasBertollo is the definition of knowns smth like ```this.knowns = [new Known()]``` Can you pls add it to your answer?

Comment: @LucasBertollo try replacing ```ngOnInit``` with ```ngAfterContentChecked```

Comment: Same error, didnt work "TypeError: this.known.checkRev is not a function"